# Why is the bitmap size smaller than other hdpi folders when put the image into xxxhdpi?

Tags: android, bitmap

Here is the code:

```
imageIv.setImageResources(R.id.icon);
```

Calculating the image bitmap size:

```
imageIv.getDrawable().getBitmap();
```

Here is the result when put the image into different folders:

```
 |  folder   | bitmap size  |
 |  ----  | ----  |
 | drawable  | 96×96->36 k |
 | xhdpi  | 96×96->36 k |
 | xxhdpi  | 96×96->36 k |
 | xxxhdpi  | 84×84->27 k |
```

The image origin size is **96×96** px.
As the above shown, why the bitmap size is different in xxxhdpi folder from other folders?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer.  Where did you get these numbers from?  How are you measuring them?  And if these are just the size of images in the folders-  those are provided by you, not created by the app.  So if one of them is the wrong size, its a problem in what people put into the folder.

Comment: There is inly one image, but i get different bitmap size when I put the image into the xxxhdpi folder.

Comment: You're not supposed to put the same image into each folder.  You're supposed to put suitably scaled versions into the different folders, if you need to (if the fidelity of the scaled image at that resolution isn't good enough.

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering why it is a different bitmap size when put the image into xxxhdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming those are mipmap images from the res folders found in the project drop menu under the project tab. [assumption based on the naming convention you gave. the xhdpi, xxhdpi, etc]

[image: a screenshot example]

there, this is the folder you are talking about. Right?

[image]

if you simply want to add an image, right-click on the res folder. from there, select image asset.

[image: image asset example]

from there, select the icon type and everything you want. then, once done, android studio would automatically generate different images for different pixel sizes.

The reason it has different image sizes is to have an image for every conventional screen size. This is done so that android doesn't have to scale down or scale up the images because, upscaled or downscaled images don't always look the best. this is mostly important when you are working with vector images. If you haven't changed anything yet in the folder, you'll find the default app icons of different sizes in there which android has generated by default. those are generated using the vector images in the drawable and drawable v26 folder. (vector images have an extension that ends with ".xml"

Comment: Thanks. If you put a image into mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi separately,  and setImageResource for the imageview. And counting the image bitmap memory, you will find memory cost is same except the image in xxxhdpi. I just want to know why.

Comment: there might be a resolution upper limit. So, if you add an image with a higher res, android studio might scale it down without you doing anything. That is the only explanation I can come up with. That would also explain why your image res gets reduced from 96*96 to 84*84.

Comment: I have the same idea with you, but I have not supported it from the source code.

Comment: You don't have to add support for a resolution restriction. It might be there by default.  also, it might be downscaling your image to 84*84 because it thinks that resolution is easier to upscale because turning 96*96 to 192*192 directly might cause aliasing problems (or in other words, pixelation issues might be easier to understand)